# How to get the value of list count in SPWeb level?

Tags: list, sharepoint-server, splist, spweb

Hi i`m making a Windows application that analyse the SharePoint Site.

In SPWeb level, I want to get the value of list count. I tried to like this

```
SPWeb.Lists.Count.ToString();
```

But when I compare with that value, it`s different, not matched...

So I want to try make code, unfortunately, I`m just beginner of SharePoint...

Please somebody help me. give some examples or links about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of the `SPWeb.Lists.Count.ToString();` return the number of all lists and libraries not only lists

To can get the accurate number of lists only you should exclude the library and other list types from your code as the following

```
int listcount=0;

foreach (SPList list in Web.Lists)
        {
            if (!list.Hidden & list.BaseType != SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary &
                (
                    (int)list.BaseTemplate != 109 |     // Picture Library
                    (int)list.BaseTemplate != 851       // Asset Library
                ))
            {
listcount++;
            }
        }
```

If you need to get only the count of custom lists, try the following :

```
int listcount=0;

foreach (SPList list in Web.Lists)
        {
            if ((int)list.BaseTemplate == 100 )
            {
       listcount++;
            }
        }
```

To check all BaseTemplateID check [Get the RegistrationId template list for a SharePoint custom action via Power Shell.](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/08/22/registrationid-template-list-sharepoint-powershell/)

Comment: Thank you M.Qassas. I made a code using your source! :) Now it works well exactly what I want!

Answer (score 6):

`SPWeb.Lists.Count.ToString();` is correct way to find number of Lists for any `SPWeb`. You might be seeing in difference in count you see here and in Site is because SharePoint has couple of hidden list like UserInformation list, managed metadata list which are hidden from UI.  Also we can hide our custom list by using powershell/server side code.

To give an idea and to identify total number of Hidden list, you can iterate through above Lists and match it with what your list on sites.

Comment: So there is another way to get list count?? for example, get by listweb id

Comment: no..whatever you do, List on SPWeb will retrieve all lists including hidden ones, you need to seperate the count manually. can you tell me what is your  purpose of get this list counts ? do you  want to display anywhere to user ?

Comment: Oh I just want to count expect hidden lists

Answer (score 3):

Try following code

```
 using (SPSite site = new SPSite("Web Url"))
  {
      using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
      {
          Console.Write(web.Lists.Count);
          Console.ReadLine();
      }
  }
```

Comment: @akshay...what he is trying and your answer is same....

Comment: yeah this is the same my code

Comment: @Siddharth Vaghasia,  Yes, you are write.My mistake. sorry.I thought code may have some issue so,I just put complete  code based on the post title(How to get the value of list count in SPWeb level?).

Comment: Akshay It`s okay! And thank you for try to help me :)